# The getter 'codeUnits' was called on null

Tags: http, flutter

It is realy simple thing but I am unable to find the reason of issue.I have 2 stateful widget A and B, in widget A's init function I am calling the netwok calls and getting api response and rendering the latest data.In B, I fill the form and pushing to the server and after successfully posting the data to server I recall the Widget A to render latest data.

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'A');
```

Now Issue is every thing is working fine but after the data updating to server when i move the the widetA, my network calls return with null .

Cases in which it works.
1) if I don't call sendingPetPost function in widget B , and Move from B to A, then it works fine.

2) from Postman api works fine , no issue of calliing multiple times , i got the response each times.

3) there is no error of null instance of http call, issue is just response is null
init function's code of A

```
  if(await utiles.isNetworkAvailbale())
       {
        model.getPostList(10, 1, 1, "", "token");
        model.getNewsList(10, 1, 1, "", "token");
        model.getEventsList(10, 1, 1, "", "token");
        model.getPetsList(35, 0, Provider.of<User>(context).id.toInt(), "token");
        print("====================================================");
       }else{
         isNetworkAvailable=false;
       }
```

Moving from Widget B to A after updating the data.

```
                                    sendingPetPost(
                                            endPOINT,
                                            widget.petDataImg,
                                            widget.isImgAdded)
                                        .whenComplete(() {
                                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'homeview');
                                    });
```

API call

```
  Future<List<Post>> getPostList(
      int pageSize, int pageNo, int cateId, String search, token) async {
    var posts = List<Post>();
    var response;
    print('$ENDPOINT/List?Type=blogs&PageNo=$pageNo&PageSize=$pageSize&Search');

    try {
      response = await client.get(
          //'$ENDPOINT/Data?PageSize=$pageSize&PageNo=$pageNo&nCategorieID=$cateId&Search=$search',
          '$ENDPOINT/List?Type=Blogs&PageNo=$pageNo&PageSize=$pageSize&Search',
          headers: headers);
    } catch (e) {
      print("error" + e.toString());
    }
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {                   
      // parse into List
      print("post =>> data received");
      var parsed = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;

      // loop and convert each item to Post
      for (var post in parsed) {
        posts.add(Post.fromJson(post));
      }
      return posts;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Error

```
errorNoSuchMethodError: The getter 'codeUnits' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 7630): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 7630): Tried calling: codeUnits
E/flutter ( 7630): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'statusCode' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7630): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7630): Tried calling: statusCode
```

**Update**

it is so strange that I put headers inside the function and now it works,

```
  Future<String> sendingPetPost(
      String _endpoint, Map<String, dynamic> map, bool isIm) async {
/// if we make _headers gloable it create exception (same exception which is described above), but if we put _headers inside the fucntion like this, then it works.
           Map<String, String> _headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'authorization':
          'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('Sau***:Sa*****'))
    };
    Dio dio = Dio();
    try {
        FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
          "pet_image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            map['path'],
            filename: map['name'],
          )
        });
     Response response = await dio.post("$ENDPOINT/AddPet?$_endpoint",
            data: formData, options: Options(headers: _headers));
       return json.decode(response.data)['message'];
    } on SocketException {
      throw Failure(UIHelper.NO_INTERNET_EXCEP);
    }
  }
```